# Smooth animation on scroll in safari

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, safari

I have an SVG vs JS animation on scroll that works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but it's quite laggy in Safari.

```
let continueAnimation = true;

// Create a variable to define when to stop the animation
const stopAtPixel = 800;

// JavaScript code to handle the scroll animation for vertical movement
const vElementsC = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="c-symbol_"]');
const vElementsA = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="a-symbol_"]');
const vElementsN = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="n-symbol_"]');
const vElementsH = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="h-symbol_"]');
const vSpeedFactorBase = 0.7;

function updateVerticalElementPositions(elements, x) {
  if (!continueAnimation && window.scrollY < stopAtPixel)
    continueAnimation = true;
  if (!continueAnimation) return;

  const scrollY = window.scrollY;
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element) {
      const distanceToMove =
        Math.pow(vSpeedFactorBase, elements.length - 1 - index) * scrollY * x;
      element.style.transform = `translateY(${-Math.round(distanceToMove)}px)`;
    }
  });
}


function updateHorizontalElementPositions() {
  const scrollY = window.scrollY;

  gElements.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element) {
      const distanceToMoveHorizontal =
        Math.pow(gSpeedFactorBase, gElements.length - 1 - index) * scrollY;
      const distanceToMoveVertical =
        Math.pow(gSpeedFactorBase, gElements.length - 1 - index) *
        scrollY *
        0.6;

      if (
        Math.round(distanceToMoveHorizontal) >= stopAtPixel &&
        index === gElements.length - 1
      ) {
        continueAnimation = false;
      }

      if (
        Math.round(distanceToMoveHorizontal) < stopAtPixel &&
        index === gElements.length - 1
      ) {
        continueAnimation = true;
      }

      if (continueAnimation) {
        element.style.transform = `translateX(${Math.round(
          distanceToMoveHorizontal
        )}px) translateY(${Math.round(distanceToMoveVertical)}px)`;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[whole code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/webstarter_run/pen/QWJedRv).

The SVG is substantial and has a raster image as the background for elements. Initially, I thought the lag was due to the many animated nodes, but when I replace the raster image with a simple gradient background, it runs smoothly in Safari as well. So, why is this issue present only in Safari?

I tried to put raster image url instead base64 code inside svg, but it didn't help.